# Trying to assign Numbers to String

Tags: c

In this C code , I am trying to assign and print out the numbers accordingly to the number of the month

EG Input = 1 , Result = January .

I have searched the web , I can't  seem to find an answer for this , I tried assigning the numbers in a {} way ,

```
{
    1 = "January" ; 
}
```

Something like above , but it does not work , may I know what i did wrongly here .

The code below solves the problem but i know its consider as bad code
Thank you !

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    
    
    int main()
    {
        int y ;
        printf("enter a value :" , y);
        scanf("%d" , &y);
        if (y>=1 || y<=12)
        {
            if (y == 1 )
            {printf("January");}
            if (y == 2 )
            {printf("February");}
            if (y == 3 )
            {printf("March");}
            if (y == 4 )
            {printf("April");}
            if (y == 5 )
            {printf("May");}
            if (y == 6 )
            {printf("June");}
            if (y == 7 )
            {printf("July");}
            if (y == 8 )
            {printf("August");}
            if (y == 9 )
            {printf("September");}
            if (y == 10 )
            {printf("October");}
            if (y == 11 )
            {printf("November");}
            if (y == 12 )
            {printf("December");}
            
        }
        
        return 0 ;
    }
```

Comment: ?? `January = 1;` ?? You can't assign anything to an integer literal, e.g. `1`, it is not an l-value. If you want to create constants, why not use a global `enum`? , e.g. `enum { January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December };` to create the named constants `January` - `December` with values `1` - `12`. Then you can `switch (y) case : January puts ("January"); break; case : February ...`

Comment: Just as a side note: It is not safe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: The `enum` will need to begin `enum { January = 1, February, ... }` otherwise the value associated with `January` will default to `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try storing them in an array like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *months[12] = {
    "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

int main()
{
    int y;
    printf("enter a value :");
    scanf("%d" , &y);
    if (y>=1 && y<=12)
    {
        printf("%s", months[y-1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```